# I need to create a lookup table in Report Server Database

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working on SSRS 2005.  I work with third party databases and I cannot create the table in those databases. My only option is to have a lookup table in the ReportServer database. 
I dont know if its possible. Is there any way to create a lookup table on the ReportServer database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a normal, SQLServer database. Assuming you have a valid username and password, simply login to the ReportServer database using SQLServer Management Studio and carry on from there.

I strongly recommend that you liaise with any SQLServer DBAs responsible for the ReportServer database in question, before proceeding to create and populate such tables.